# Is there a way to use emacs like a speadsheet?

Tags: emacs

Is there a package where I can format my text file like a speadsheet in emacs?

Comment: are you talking about converting it into csv or a tab seperated file ?

Comment: @Shark Convert to csv

Comment: you could try replacing all single spaces " " with "," . In my opinion a spreadsheet is a better tool to convert a text file into csv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Org-mode is part of emacs and has excellent table editing support, including spreadsheet functionality.

- http://orgmode.org
- http://orgmode.org/manual/The-spreadsheet.html

Moreover, you can use org-mode's table functionality within other emacs major modes:

- http://orgmode.org/manual/Orgtbl-mode.html

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [ses-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SimpleEmacsSpreadsheet) (Simple Emacs Spreadsheet)? There is also a [ses2any script](http://furius.ca/pubcode/pub/conf/bin/ses2any) that will convert ses-mode spreadsheets  to a few other spreadsheet formats (CSV, Excel, HTML).